# How i can install wordpress & joomla in ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: software-installation, wordpress, joomla, cms

I am new in linux. I already install lampp server with php my admin in ubuntu 13.04. But I can not install any cms like wordpress, joomla & cannot access from browser address bar. Please help me.

Comment: Do you have LAMP installed?

Comment: You have to describe the problems you have with installing those things more detailled. Please describe what you tried, what happened, and what you expected to happen, otherwise nobody will be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

**Install Joomla!**

Easiest way to install Joomla is [Bitnami-Joomla!](http://docs.joomla.org/Installing_Joomla_on_Debian_Linux#BitNami_Joomla.21_stack) stack.

To install joomla! follow these steps;

```
cd ~/Downloads

sudo wget -c http://downloads.bitnami.com/files/stacks/joomla/3.2.0-0/bitnami-joomla-3.2.0-0-linux-x64-installer.run

sudo chmod +x bitnami-joomla-3.2.0-0-linux-x64-installer.run

sudo ./bitnami-joomla-3.2.0-0-linux-x64-installer.run
```

Then the ***Installer Setup*** will load and you just need to proceed with it !

Answer (score 0):

Have you used the software center? Alternatively, you can use the terminal and run these codes `sudo apt-get install wordpress`- That is for wordpress.

Joomla? I am not too well rehearsed in this applicant, so here is a good tutorial! 
http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/02/how-to-install-joomla-25x-on-ubuntu.html

If it helped, thumbs up! Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I too am new to linux. I have a virtual Ubuntu LAMP server running on Windows 7 host using VM VirtualBox. It is the first time i have ever setup a linux based web server. After installing Ubuntu 12.04 i decided to create a second virtual server using Ubuntu 13.10. Based on the problems i am having with release 13.10m my advice to you for now is...

go back to Ubuntu desktop 12.04.

I found installing LAMP and Wordpress on that version very easy. I had a few permissions problems to sort out in Ubuntu 12.04 after the install but it all went reasonably well.

Using tasksel as (outlined in wiki) for 13.10 wasted hours of my time...i ended up starting over with a fresh Ubuntu OS and installing LAMP components separately using synaptic. I got it first go this way. However, i for the life of me cannot get ftp to work with release 13 (even though its easy to get working in Ubuntu 12)